# Cosa significa in questo contesto “ Perché tutto e niente ci apparteneva”?

Tags: meaning

"E quando saremo vecchi e tu mi dirai:
Come siamo arrivati ​​fino a qui insieme?
Ti risponderò:
Perché invece di urlare, parliamo. Invece di scappare, cerchiamo soluzioni. Perché tutto e niente ci apparteneva, perché abbiamo pianto e riso insieme. Perché un giorno abbiamo promesso di stare insieme nel bene e nel male e soprattutto perché l'amore è cresciuto nel tempo sotto forma di un amore che non muore mai ".

Comment: E qual è ”questo contesto”?

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! Dare la fonte per questo stralcio sarebbe molto utile per produrre una risposta appropriata

Answer (score 1):

È un ossimoro (una contraddizione), e in quanto tale va interpretato non in maniera letterale, ma in maniera metaforica. Col poco contesto che abbiamo, è difficile ricavare il significato preciso: potrebbe voler riferirsi al fatto che gli amanti hanno pochi beni materiali (niente) ma nonostante questo sono contenti del loro amore (hanno 'tutto' ciò che conta). In ogni caso, si tratta di una frasetta da smemoranda, di scarso valore letterario, quindi non mi scervellerei su significati profondi: una frase ad effetto, e nulla più.